# Is this integral with sine and cosine such a challenge?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

...or maybe I just don't know some specific trick with trigonometric functions?

Well, anyway, here it is: 
$$\int{\sin^6{x}\cos^4{x}\, dx}$$

I'm bored with it, because I get 9 integrals out of 1 and the whole thing frustrates me as hell. 
So, is there a simpler way of integrating this or should I just make up my mind to it and integrate and integrate and integrate and integrate...untill the end comes?

By the way, here's the answer:
$$ \frac{3 x}{256}-\frac{1}{512} \sin (2 x)-\frac{1}{256} \sin (4 x)+\frac{\sin (6 x)}{1024}+\frac{\sin (8 x)}{2048}-\frac{\sin (10 x)}{5120}$$

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the "power-reducing" section on this [website](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html). It is tedious to do...

Comment: @user88595 theres a fairly non-tedious way to do this using complex analysis. Check out my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\sin^2 x = \frac{1 - \cos 2x}{2}, \; \cos^2 x = \frac{1 + \cos 2x}{2}
$$

Further you use a generalized version of these if you're comfortable with complex numbers:
$$
\cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}, \sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}
$$
and then use the binomial theorem:
$$
(a + b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k}
$$

Comment: So, thanks a lot, I've done everything I needed with your help, It was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

To simplify things, use the fact that $(e^{ix})^n=\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)$, comparing real and imaginary parts, you can linearize sins and cosines of any powers.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

$$\int\sin^6x\cos^4xdx=\int\sin^4x\cos^4x(\sin^2x)dx=\frac1{32}\int\sin^42x(1-\cos2x)dx=$$
$$\frac1{32}\int\sin^42xdx-\frac1{32}\int\sin^42x\cos2xdx$$

This should cut your work down quite a bit.